# Speed test reading counting words per second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says I'm trying to make a speed test reading counter and for some reason it always gives me "inifinty" and I can't figure out the reason. Console doesn't give anykind of error

HTML

```
<button class="btn" id="start" onclick="start();">Start Reading</button>
<div id="page1" style="display: block;">text goes here</div>
<button class="btn" id="stop" onclick="stop();">Finished!</button>
<span id="wordValue"></span>
<span id="timeValue"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
jQuery('#stop').click(function(){
jQuery('#timeValue').append(getSeconds());
jQuery('#wordValue').append(Math.round(wordCount('#page1')));
jQuery('#wordValue').append(wpm);
jQuery('#wordValue').append(difference);
});

Stopwatch();

function Stopwatch(){
  var startTime, endTime, instance = this;

  this.start = function (){
    startTime = new Date();
  };

  this.stop = function (){
    endTime = new Date();
  }

  this.clear = function (){
    startTime = null;
    endTime = null;
  }

  this.getSeconds = function(){
    if (!endTime){
    return 0;
    }
    return Math.round((endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
  }

  this.getMinutes = function(){
    return instance.getSeconds() / 60;
  }      
  this.getHours = function(){
    return instance.getSeconds() / 60 / 60;
  }    
  this.getDays = function(){
    return instance.getHours() / 24;
  }   

  this.wordCount = function wordCount(text){
     testWords = (jQuery(text).text().length) / 5;
     return testWords;
  }

    wpm = Math.round(wordCount('#page1') / (getSeconds() / 60));
   difference = Math.round(100*((wpm/250)-1));

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why the code doesn't work: *wpm* and *difference* are calculated when you call `Stopwatch`, but you should only calculate these when the clock is stopped. As you do it upon calling `Stopwatch`, `getSeconds()` will detect `endTime` is not yet defined and return 0. As you use that result in the denominator, you get a division by 0, which in JavaScript gives Infinity.

But you should not only correct that, as there are some other issues:

1. You use the `this` keyword in `Stopwatch` as if that function is a constructor, but you never use it as a constructor. To do that you should call the function with the `new` keyword, and assign the created object to a variable, which you will need to access its methods (`start`, `stop`, ...). As you have it now, `this` just becomes a synonym for `window`, and if you were to use `strict mode`, JavaScript would complain about that.

   So, you can either remove the `this` prefix, or make `Stopwatch` a true constructor. The first option is not really nice, as you then continue to change variables in the global scope from within a function. This is considered bad design. So I will present the code using `Stopwatch` as a constructor.
2. You have click handler on the *stop* button both in HTML and in the JavaScript code. Also that is bad design as it leaves doubt as to what is executed first. I'd suggest to bind your JavaScript code to the elements via JavaScript only, not in HTML.
3. You use jQuery's `append` to append pure text. First, by always appending the results the readability is quite bad, and consecutive results will stick to each other. Secondly, `append` is suited for adding HTML. For text you should use the `text` method. And different parts of text should better be put in separate HTML containers.

Here is corrected code. The comments should clarify the changes:

```js
// Use stopwatch as a constructor with `this` being the created object:
var watch = new Stopwatch();

// Bind the event handlers to both the buttons. No more HTML `onclick` attributes.
jQuery('#start').click(watch.start);
jQuery('#stop').click(function(){
  if (watch.getSeconds() === null) {
    alert('you did not start yet!');
    return;
  }
  //Stop the clock
  watch.stop();
  // create wpm and difference here:
  var wpm = Math.round(wordCount('#page1') / (watch.getSeconds() / 60));
  var difference = Math.round(100*((wpm/250)-1));
  // refer to watch's methods, and use text()
  jQuery('#timeValue').text(watch.getSeconds());
  // Make sure to replace the previous result, and give some clarity in the output
  jQuery('#wordValue').text(Math.round(wordCount('#page1')));
  jQuery('#speed').text(wpm);
  jQuery('#difference').text(difference + '%');
});

function Stopwatch(){
  var startTime, endTime, instance = this;

  this.start = function (){
    startTime = new Date();
  };

  this.stop = function (){
    endTime = new Date();
  }

  this.clear = function (){
    startTime = null;
    endTime = null;
  }

  this.getSeconds = function(){
    // return non-numerical value to indicate timer was not started
    if (!startTime){
      return null;
    }
    if (!endTime){
      return 0;
    }
    return Math.round((endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
  }

  this.getMinutes = function(){
    return instance.getSeconds() / 60;
  }      
  this.getHours = function(){
    return instance.getSeconds() / 60 / 60;
  }    
  this.getDays = function(){
    return instance.getHours() / 24;
  }   
}

// create separate function that has little to do with the stopwatch:
function wordCount(text){
  testWords = (jQuery(text).text().length) / 5;
  return testWords;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="start" >Start Reading</button>
<div id="page1" style="display: block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<button class="btn" id="stop" >Finished!</button><br>
Words: <span id="wordValue"></span><br>
Speed: <span id="speed"></span><br>
Difference: <span id="difference"></span><br>
Seconds: <span id="timeValue"></span><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

It gives infinity wpm, because it gets intialised on page load.  So the word count is correct, but getSeconds() always returns 0. I put that along with stop button and it is ok I think. Take a look please.

```
        <button class="btn" id="start" onclick="start();">Start Reading</button>
    <div id="page1" style="display: block;">text goes here
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    Where does it come from?
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

    Where can I get some?
    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.



    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="stop" onclick="stop();">Finished!</button><br/>

    <span id="wordValue"></span> words <br/>
    <span id="timeValue"></span> time <br/>
    <span id="wpm"></span> WPM Speed <br/>
    <span id="diff"></span> difference


        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
           jQuery('#stop').click(function(){

                jQuery('#timeValue').append(getSeconds());
                jQuery('#wordValue').append(Math.round(wordCount('#page1')));
                jQuery('#wpm').append(wpm);
                jQuery('#diff').append(difference);
            });


    Stopwatch();
    function Stopwatch(){
      var startTime, endTime, instance = this;

      this.start = function (){ 
        startTime = new Date();
        alert(startTime);
      };

      this.stop = function (){
        endTime = new Date();

       wpm = Math.round(wordCount('#page1') / (getSeconds() / 60));
       alert(Math.round(wordCount('#page1')));
       alert(getSeconds() / 60);
       difference = Math.round(100*((wpm/250)-1));
      };

      this.clear = function (){
        startTime = null;
        endTime = null;
      };

      this.getSeconds = function(){
        if (!endTime){
        return 0;
        }
        return Math.round((endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
      };

      this.getMinutes = function(){
        return instance.getSeconds() / 60;
      } ;     
      this.getHours = function(){
        return instance.getSeconds() / 60 / 60;
      } ;   
      this.getDays = function(){
        return instance.getHours() / 24;
      } ;  

      this.wordCount = function wordCount(text){
         testWords = (jQuery(text).text().length) / 5;
         return testWords;
      };



        }
     } );
        </script>
```